# Iteration on Quick Sort

Tags: c++

I was trying to implement quick sort now. But, i have some problem with the loop part below

```
for (int current = 0; current <= high - 1; current++)
```

When i initialize that 'current' statement with 0, it show nothing on the screen when i run it. Then, i try to replace it with 'low' argument like in the implementation provided and it was run appropriately.

What i want to ask is, why it doesn't work when i initialize the loop statement with 0, which was the same value assigned to 'low' parameter? I have tried initialize new variable with 0 and use that variable to the loop, but it give the same result like when i directly assign the loop statement with 0. Thanks for the answer.

Here the code:

```
int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];
    int index = (low - 1);
    for (int current = low; current <= high - 1; current++)
    {
        if (arr[current] <= pivot)
        {
            index++;
            swap(arr[index], arr[current]);
        }
    }
    swap(arr[index+1], arr[high]);
    return (index + 1);
}

void quicksort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);
        quicksort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quicksort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 3, 4, 2, 5, 1 };
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    quicksort(arr, 0, n-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

[The result when i set the 'current' value with 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/731If.png)

Comment: Recursive calls use the same array, but should operate only on their part of it. When you start current from 0, you violate this part of recursive call "agreement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`low` is only 0 in the first call to `partition`; it takes different values in other calls. Note that when `quicksort` calls itself the second time, `low` will get assigned `pi + 1`.

Print it out in the beginning of `partition` to observe this for some known not-too-large array - this should be a good educational exercise in general. I mean make the first line of `partition`:

```
cout << "low = " << low << "\n";
```